# VBA Delete Columns with less than 5 values

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have found lots of posts to delete empty columns - however I need to delete columns with less than 5 values inside it.

There are 1000 columns I need only the ones that have more than 5 values inside them.

If it can be done via VBA better

just to clairfy i mean five values for example not number 5

Thank You

Can not find anything to requirement

Comment: Loop through each columns, run a `counta()` function on them. If less than 5, then delete. That's probably the approach I would use.

Answer (score 1):

For some unknown reason you tagged for Powerquery while asking about VBA, so here is Powerquery M code to only keep columns with more than 5 non-null rows

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
keep = Table.SelectRows(Table.AddColumn(Table.Profile(Source), "Custom", each Table.RowCount(Source)-[NullCount]), each [Custom] > 5)[Column],
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,keep)  
in #"Removed Other Columns"
```

Comment: thanks I did in case I was unable to find VBA solution - i run your power query whilst it did run I had to stop after  5 hours crashing pc and taking too long - maybe for someone with smaller data this will work better - i have 32 GB RAM not sure if there is extra setting to allocate more to excel somewhere in windows

Comment: You didn't provide detail on the code you are using nor on the amount of data you are processing, so its hard to help beyond this